# yaml for creating a deployment fails

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

After building a docker image named my-http I can create a deployment from it with

> kubectl create deploy http-deployment --image=my-http

This will not pull the image because imagePullPolicy is Always.

So then run

> kubectl edit deploy http-deployment

and change the imagePullPolicy to Never, then it runs.

But for automation purposes I've created a yaml to create the deployment and set the imagePullPolicy at the same time.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: http-deployment
spec:
    replicas: 3
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: http
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: http
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: my-http
          image: my-http
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
```

Then apply -f and the pods start running but after a while a Crashloopbackoff starts with the message

> container image my-http already present on machine

Apparently it has something to do with the container port but what to use for that port to get it running? There is no container running...

edit: the image already present is just informational, this is the last line in the pod description

> Warning  BackOff    7s (x8 over 91s)    kubelet, minikube  Back-off
> restarting failed container

Comment: does that container runs using docker run? What does `kubectl logs podname` say ?

Comment: that says nothing :)

Answer (score 3):

If you using kubernetes cluster your images only available on the nodes that you build the images.

You have to push images to container registries then the kubernetes will try to pull the image to node that will running the container.

If you want to run the container in the nodes that you build the images you have to use NodeSelector, or PodAffinity.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/

Answer (score 1):

Your image is probably private image which Kubernetes can't pull if you didn't specify [imagePullSecrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).

This shouldn't be the problem however, because `imagePullPolicy: Never` would just use the image on the nodes. You can diagnose real problem by either `kubectl describe pod pod_name` or getting logs of the previous pod with `--previous` flag because newer pod may not have encountered the problem.

Comment: Also tried minikube delete and create master node VM with the image anew. Same problem. First image is pulled succesfully, goes briefly in running state and then Crash without log. I'll try to pull from docker repository when have the time. See what that does.

Comment: There is something wrong with your deployment then. Just try any other image like ngix to see if your kubernetes cluster works correctly.